# Phone charger on 9 V battery calculations

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging

I have a phone that holds 4500 mAh. I have a potential circuit (I'm trying to build for educational purposes) to hook up a 9 V battery to charge the phone via USB. The battery holds 550 mAh.

First calculation: this particular battery can potentially charge the phone to 12% (=550/4500). Is this the correct calculation (obviously, there's some energy loss, but theoretically speaking)?

Second calculation: if the above is correct, how long will it take to charge the 12% with that battery? I don't know how to calculate that, but the only other variable I have is the phone's fast-charger is a 30 W USB cable.

Comment: Compare the voltages and compute the _energy_ in each battery.

Comment: The phone does not have 9V battery so the mAh don't compare. And time depends on what current you use. At 1mA it will take 550 hours. At 550mA it will take 1 hour. At 1100mA it takes half an hour. The problem is, in real world we don't have ideal batteries. The phone takes whatever current it wants and the 9V battery has very large internal resistance so it won't have 550mAh available at 550mA. 30W is something unachievable for 9V battery.

Comment: How can I determine the current the phone takes in? If I hook it to a normal charger, can I detect the current there?

Comment: What is the circuit you are building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say, without knowing your phone's specific power negotiation, that it defaults to (and allows) charging at 1 USB power unit load, 100mA.  Let's also assume that you're using a buck converter with 100% efficiency and zero dropout voltage.  According to the [datasheet for this 9V battery](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Duracell/PX1604.pdf), you should get ~4h of use before the voltage drops below 5V.  Also from the chart, you can see that battery voltage essentially falls off a cliff at 6V so there's no real utility in trying to boost anything below 5V.

100mA at 5V for 4 hours gives you 400mAh at 5V, or 2Wh.  Phone batteries are specced in mAh, but the voltage is usually not 5V.  Let's assume your phone's battery is 3.7V nominal, which gives 16.65Wh.  So, assuming 100% conversion efficiencies all the way, you will be able to charge your phone 12% off of a 628mAh 9V battery (14% bigger than the one in your example, the numbers just happened to match up by accident).

What are some reasonable efficiency numbers you can expect?  A good switching converter (don't even think about using a 7805!) could get maybe 95%, which leaves you with 1.9Wh.  Assuming the charging circuitry in your phone is about the same (high 90s seem to be reasonable and the Coulombic efficiency of a lithium ion battery is ~99%), you get about 1.8Wh, so just less than 11% of a full charge in 4 hours.

Comment: This is great analysis, but I read that devices can draw up to 6 unit loads (900 mA) on USB 3.0 -- does that mean, essentially, your ending 4-hour estimate could be reduced to ~26 minutes (= 4h / (900/100))?

Comment: 9V batteries aren't really designed to provide that much current so the amount of usable energy in the battery would drop.  The curve for 25mA discharge shows you'd be able to get ~24 hours before voltage dropped below 5V: 600mAh.  Tripling the current to 75mA gets you *less* than 1/3 of the useful life, somewhat more than 6 hours for ~500mAh.  Could you crank it up to 900mA?  Probably, but you'd be getting less than an 11% charge.  Your phone battery's Coulombic efficiency would drop too; notice how it gets hot when you're fast charging?  That's wasted energy ending up as heat.

Answer (score 1):

First, [assume a spherical phone in a vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow). And a spherical battery.

You are using some kind of voltage converter to convert 9V to 5V. Either you are using a linear regulator or a switching regulator. Linear regulators preserve mA (and mAh) and switching regulators preserve mW (and mWh).

If you use a linear regulator, you get a total 550mAh at 5V. If you use a switching regulator, you get 990mAh at 5V.

Your phone battery is specified as 3.7 volts (I guarantee it). Your phone contains a switching regulator which puts 743mAh into the battery if you used linear or 1337mAh (nice) if you used switching.

*This is a rough, back-of-the-envelope calculation.* The big source of inaccuracy is that batteries aren't constant voltages. A 9V battery may start at 9.6V and be dead when it gets to 6.0V. Your phone battery (lithium-ion) is about 3.2V when flat and 4.2V when full. If you use a switching regulator, it has an efficient rating. Your phone uses power because it's turned on, so the battery goes down at the same time it's going up. The more slowly you use up the battery, the more total energy you get - draining it quickly is inefficient.

---

As for the speed, it depends greatly on the phone and the charge circuit. The phone is supposed to control the amount of current it draws from the charger based on several factors.

The phone is supposed to only take a certain amount of current (I think 100mA) until it talks to the charger and agrees to take more. Some phones might just *assume* you've plugged them into a sensible power source, and take 500mA as that is the maximum available in the oldest version of USB. Often you can alternatively connect some resistors to the data pins to signal what charging current is available.

There's not much consistency here. One thing that sources do seem to agree on is that shorting the two data pins together indicates your charger is a Dedicated Charging Port which means the phone can take 1.8A. But your battery won't like that - that will drain it much too quickly and waste a lot of energy.

You could maybe charge at that 1.8A speed if you charged from multiple AA batteries, instead of a 9V. Even 500mA is seriously pushing it for a 9V. 100mA is probably okay but it'll take forever and the phone battery will probably still go down because the phone is on.

Comment: great analysis, too... the two answers combined make a lot of sense..
I'll just give the answer to first responder